# How to use substitute() to loop lme functions from nlme package?

Tags: r, lapply, lme4, mixed-models, nlme

I am trying to use [`lme`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/nlme/html/lme.html) function from `nlme` package inside a `lapply` loop. This works for `lmer` function from [`lme4`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/lme4.pdf) package, but produces an error message for `lme`. How can I loop `lme` functions similarly to the `lmer` function in the example below?

```
library("nlme")
library("lme4")

set.seed(1)
dt <- data.frame(Resp1 = rnorm(100, 50, 23), Resp2 = rnorm(100, 80, 15), Pred = rnorm(100,10,2), group = factor(rep(LETTERS[1:10], each = 10)))

## Syntax:
lmer(Resp1 ~ Pred + (1 |group), data = dt)
lme(Resp1 ~ Pred, random = ~1 | group, data = dt)

## Works for lme4
lapply(c("Resp1", "Resp2"), function(k) {
  lmer(substitute(j ~ Pred + (1 | group), list(j = as.name(k))), data = dt)})

## Does not work for nlme
lapply(c("Resp1", "Resp2"), function(k) {
lme(substitute(j ~ Pred, list(j = as.name(k))), random = ~1 | group, data = dt)})

# Error in UseMethod("lme") : 
# no applicable method for 'lme' applied to an object of class "call"
```

PS. I am aware that [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24748724/looping-in-nlme) exists, but I would like to use a method substituting response variable directly in the model function instead of subsetting data using an additional function.

Comment: try adding `eval` to process the `call` object?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Jep. That does the trick. Thanks! The answer is `lme(eval(substitute(j ~ Pred, list(j = as.name(k)))), random = ~1 | group, data = dt)`

Comment: Mikko,  glad that did it.  Feel free to post the answer yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of fiddling around with `substitute` and `eval` you also could do the following:

```
lapply(c("Resp1", "Resp2"), function(r) {
   f <- formula(paste(r, "Pred", sep = "~"))
   m <- lme(fixed = f, random = ~ 1 | group, data = dt)
   m$call$fixed <- f
   m})
```

You could use the same trick if you want to provide different data sets to a modelling function:

```
makeModel <- function(dat) {
   l <- lme(Resp1 ~ Pred, random = ~ 1 | group, data = dat)
   l$call$data <- as.symbol(deparse(substitute(dat)))
   l
}
```

I use this snippet quite a bit, when I want to generate a model from within a function and want to update it afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

As @CarlWitthoft suggested, adding `eval` into the function will solve the issue:

```
lapply(c("Resp1", "Resp2"), function(k) {
lme(eval(substitute(j ~ Pred, list(j = as.name(k)))), random = ~1 | group, data = dt)})
```

Also see @thothal's alternative.